# break out of loop that's being enumerated

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

I want to break out of a loop that's being enumerated.

Here's an example of my problem:

```
for(NSArray *x in retrieved_data){

  for(NSDictionary *someJson in array_that_is_enumerated){

     if(intersection_of_retrieved_data_indicates_deletion_in_array){
         [array_that_is_being_enumerated removeObject:someJson];

         // can't call return; here: it's important outer for loop finishes.
         // break; will only have effect in this scope

     } else {// perform other logic}
  }

}
```

How can I still delete this object and jump to the first `for/in` loop again?

Comment: Does it HAVE to be deleted before resuming? If not then I'd create another dictionary, add the objects to it, then after I finish the first enumeration, I go back and delete the objects that match my second dictionary.

Comment: But with xcode you cannot delete objects from arrays while enumerating them, so if you HAVE to delete your objects while enumerating then you must change your approach

Comment: @Aggressor This has **nothing** to do with Xcode. It's related to iterating an `NSMutableArray` using fast enumeration. You can delete from the mutable array while using a regular `for` loop instead.

Comment: I didn't know this, I always got 'cannot remove from array while enumerating it'. I'll have to look into this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `break` terminates the closest enclosing loop, so a `break` in your `if` moves to the next iteration of your outer loop, which from:

> can't call return; here: it's important outer for loop finishes

appears to be exactly what you want.

Terminating *multiple* nested loops can be messy, you can do things like: use a label and `goto`; set a flag to test in each loop; or wrap the loops in a function/method/block and `return`.

HTH

**Addendum**

There appears to be some concern in comments/answers about deleting while enumerating, while this is completely correct you *can* delete within an enumerating loop provided you then terminate the loop - it is proceeding to the next iteration which is not allowed. So what the OP is doing, a test-delete-break, is perfectly OK.

**After Comment**

Following on from addendum, here is some sample code:

```
NSArray *outer = @[@"one", @"three", @"dog"];

NSMutableArray *inner = @[@"one", @"two", @"cat", @"dog"].mutableCopy;

NSLog(@"Before: %@", inner);
for (NSString *wordToDelete in outer)
{
   NSLog(@"Consider: %@", wordToDelete);
   for (NSString *item in inner)
   {
      if ([item isEqualToString:wordToDelete])
      {
         NSLog(@"Removing and breaking");
         [inner removeObject:item];
         break;
      }
   }
   // break lands here
}
NSLog(@"After: %@", inner);
```

The final result is `@[ @"two", @"cat" ]`. The inner loop terminates and the outer one completes. It is legitimate to do this, what would be incorrect would be doing an iteration *after* `inner` was modified.

Comment: Thanks, however I hoped that there could be a better way to do this, using a goto label is something that i'm not really feeling confident about since I'm not an expert in C memory management. This leaves me with no other choice then to wrap it up in methods, which would make the code harder to maintain unfortunately. Thanks for the excellent answer though!

Comment: @bdv - I'm probably misunderstanding your need, but in case not I've added a simple example to show how you can use `break` to terminate the inner loop while completing the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get what you want without `break`.  It seems the job of that inner loop is to identify elements in array_that_is_enumerated that should be deleted, and that decision depends on the elements in retrieved_data.

@Agressor is right that you cannot delete while enumerating, so how about isolating the deletion condition in a function?

```
// this could be done neatly as an NSPredicate, too
- (NSDictionary *)itemInInnerArrayThatShouldBeDeleted:(NSArray *)xFromRetrievedData {
    for (NSDictionary *someJson in array_that_is_enumerated) {
        if (intersection_of_retrieved_data_indicates_deletion_in_array) {
            return someJson;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Now your outer loop collects elements to be deleted as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *deleteThese = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSArray *x in retrieved_data) {
    NSDictionary *someJson = [self itemInInnerArrayThatShouldBeDeleted:x];
    if (someJson) [deleteThese addObject:someJson];
}
// now that we are done enumerating, we can safely delete
[array_that_is_enumerated removeObjectsInArray:deleteThese];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Although I'm not entirely satisfied with the approach and this code handles the deletion in a different manner that I proposed (and this won't work in my use case) it's unfortunately the best approach. Just like @CRD says, you can delete during enumeration and that's very important in this case.